# Tengo un error al para enviar a mi base de datos desde mi Formulario

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, xampp

Edit: Si estoy usando un formulario en Html, se me olvidó comentarlo
Edit2: Ya agregué el codigo html hasta abajo

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de youtube para hacer mi tarea, pero no llega a enviar los datos a la base de datos, y me regresa el mensaje que coloqué para los errores

Estoy usando XAMPP
Tengo los archivos en C:\xampp\htdocs\Base de datos
y los abro desde http://localhost/Base%20de%20datos/index.html

Este es mi código PHP

```
  <?php
    //conectamos Con el servidor
    $server ="localhost";
    $user ="root";
    $pass ="";
    $db="proyecto";

 //funcion llamada conexion con (dominio,usuarios,contraseña,base_de_datos)
 $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);
 mysqli_select_db($conexion,$db);

 //recuperar las variables
    $Nombre=$_POST['Nombre'];
    $Apellidop=$_POST['Apellidop'];
    $Apellidom=$_POST['Apellidom'];
    $Domicilio=$_POST['Domicilio'];
    $Correoe=$_POST['Correoe'];
    $Numerot=$_POST['Numerot'];
    
    //hacemos la sentencia de sql
    $sql="INSERT INTO registros VALUES('$Nombre','$Apellidop','$Apellidom','$Domicilio','$Correoe','$Numerot')";

    //ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
    $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql); 
    
 //verificamos la ejecucion
 if(!$ejecutar){
    echo"Hubo Algun Error";
   }else{
    echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
   }
?>
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Joshua Castro Ramirez</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>    
<body background="Port2.jpg">
    <div class="form">
        <form action="guardar.php" method="POST"> 
                <!-- Campos de texto -->
            <h2 class="datosP">1. Datos Personales</h2><br />
                <label for="Nombre" > Nombre <sup>*</sup></label><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Joshua" name="Nombre" id="Nombre"/><br />

            <label for="AP"> Apellido Paterno <sup>*</sup></label><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Castro" name="Apellidop" id="Apellidop" /><br />

            <label for="AM"> Apellido Materno <sup>*</sup></label><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ramirez" name="Apellidom" id="Apellidom" /><br />
            <label for="Domicilio"> Domicilio <sup>*</sup></label><br />
            <input type="text" name="Domicilio" id="Domicilio" /><br /><br />
            <label for="CE"> Correo Electronico <sup>*</sup></label><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="ejemplo@outlook.com" name="Correoe" id="Correoe" /><br><br>
            <label for="Tel"> Telefono <sup>*</sup></label><br />
            <input type="tel" name="Numerot" id="Numerot" value="781" /><br />
            <!-- Campos de texto -->
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
                <br><br>    
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No hay error en el nombre de las columnas de la base de datos ni en los input

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero uses *mysqli_error* (ver https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php según tu estructura corresponda) para que veas el error y lo pongas (de momento) en el lugar de `echo"Hubo Algun Error";`.  Respecto a *"No hay error en el nombre de las columnas[...]"_ te comento que no las usas en tu código; otra opción es que obtengas el `$sql` para que pruebes ese `INSERT` que se arma desde phpMyAdmin u otra forma aplicación web o de escritorio que tengas.

Comment: En mensaje de error usa esto mejor: `printf("Hubo Algun Error: %s\n", mysqli_error());` y revisa que error te engrega, puede ser que los campos de insercion sean mas o esten en otro orden. Publica que mensaje te esta dando como error

Answer (score 0):

Debes especificar en que columnas se guardarán esos datos, de esta forma:

```
//hacemos la sentencia de sql
$sql="INSERT INTO registros (columna1, columna2, columna3, columna4, columna5, columna6) VALUES ('$Nombre','$Apellidop','$Apellidom','$Domicilio','$Correoe','$Numerot')";
```

Posteriormente ejecutamos:

```
//ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
$ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

Y continuas con las siguientes lineas de código...

Espero te sirva, cualquier duda espero comentarios,

Comment: Se entiende bien que son las filas donde irán ubicados lo datos, el autor de la pregunta no específica las filas que tiene.

Comment: Ok ya edito, gracias por el aporte  :D